# Collision detection complexity <O(n²): Simpler approach than grid, quadtrees, BSP?

Tags: algorithm, collision-detection, spatial

I have a large number of object (balls, for a start) that move stepwise in space, one at a time, and shall not overlap. Currently, for every move I check for collision with every other object. [Several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414553/broad-phase-collision-detection-quadtrees-bsp-etc) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896280/avoid-on2-complexity-for-collision-detection) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345838/ball-to-ball-collision-detection-and-handling) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544431/collision-detection-of-huge-number-of-circles) deal with this, however, I thought of a seemingly simple solution that does not seem to come up in this context, and I wonder why.

Why not simply keep 2 collections (for 2D, or 3 in three dimensions) of all objects, sorted by the x and y (and z) coordinate, respectively, and at every move look up all other objects within a given distance (ball diameter here) in each dimension and do the actual collision check only on objects in both (or all 3) result sets?

I realize this only works for equally-sized objects, but alternatively one could use twice as many collections, sorted by the (1) highest (2) lowest coordinate of each object for each dimension. Any reason why this would not work, or give significantly less of an improvement compared to going from O(n) "pairwise check" to "[grid method](http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/models/m_colide.htm)" or "quad/octrees"? I see the update of these sorted collections as the costly operation here, but using e.g. a TreeSet (my implementation would be in Java) it should still be significantly less than O(n), right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The check for which objects are in both result sets involves looking at all objects in two strips of the plane.  That is a much larger area, and therefore involves more objects, than the enclosing square that a quadtree lets you immediately narrow down to.  More objects means that it is slower.

Comment: Oh, right! Maybe the fact that Java's Sets already have convenient methods for set intersection prevented me from considering this a bottleneck. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a spatial index or space-filling-curve instead of a quadtree. A sfc reduce the 2d complexity to a 1d complexity and is different from a quadtree because it can only store 1 object per x,y pair? Maybe this works for your problem? You want to search for Nick's hilbert curve quadtree spatial index blog.